# Latex files not compiling due to buffer size

Tags: tex-core, texmf

So I have some Latex files with large eps images which cause a `buf_size` error.
When I was compiling the files a few months ago I solved the problem by increasing the buffer size in `texmf.cnf`. I have updated TeXLive recently on both Linux and Mac and so had to do it again. When I add the following on the Mac `buf_size=2000000`, it works fine, but I get the problem with too small a buffer size no matter how large I am making it on Linux.  I am running Fedora and TeXLive 2014. Any ideas?

So I made the suspect file smaller and it now compiles on Linux but that does not explain why the `buf_size` in the  `texmf.cnf` file fixes it with the larger image on Mac but not Linux. Not sure where I can post the offending files so that others can try.

I am modifying the file in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf`

Comment: Can you make one of the `eps` files available for download from somewhere and add a link here? Sometimes the size of an `eps` file can be significantly reduced, without affecting the image quality.

Comment: Is your source compatible with `lualatex`?  It's a much newer implementation that supports dynamic expansion of many of the buffers that cause trouble.

Comment: are you using latex or pdflatex? (latex does not need to read the eps file at all)

Answer (score 5):

`buff_size` is used as the input line buffer for tex sources and also the buffer that is used for macro expansion.

So the only place that I think it is used for graphics inclusion is looking for the bounding box. If you look in the file you should see a comment of the form

```
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
```

presumably with a line of >2000000 characters before it (a tiff preview??)

if you use

```
\includegraphics[bb=19 19 221 221]{your_file}
```

using whatever numbers are appropriate for your EPS, then LaTeX will not need to read the file for the bounding box. In that case latex will not read the file at all (the actual file inclusion is done by the dvi driver such as dvips)
If you are using pdftex or luatex then they effectively act as their own drivers and so will need to include the file, but not line-by-line using the input buffer.